# Driving Relay using ESP-01 Module

Tags: circuit-analysis, relay, esp8266

I am trying to control a 5V relay with a push button with an indicator LED using GPIOs 0, 1 and 3. I have pulled up the GPIO0 and using it as output, so that when I drive it low, the LED should glow, but its not happening. Is there anything wrong with my schematic?

[image]

Comment: perhaps you should be asking about the switch led, not about your project ... please add the datasheet for the switch

Comment: I will try to find it. The issue I am facing is that when I write the code in Arduino for just blinking the LED and switching the relay on/off at 1 second intervals, nothing happens.

Comment: what troubleshooting have you done? ... did you measure the voltage across the relay and across the led? ... how do you know that the code actually runs as expected?

Comment: The reason could be anything as trivial as a broken wire. So you should add more info to the question.

Comment: GPIO0 sees +5V through LED1 + R6, that will cause trouble later, if not now.

Comment: @jay wouldnt the led drop around 2V ?

Comment: @jsotola will do that and report back

Comment: The relay I am using has a coil resistance of 70 Ohms, so I will need around 70 mA to drive it. Conservatively I will take 80 mA on the safe side. So, taking a safe gain of 20, I will need 4 mA base current. I will take a safe figure of 5mA. Taking 1V as Vbe, (3.3-1)/5ma = ~ 4K resistor.

Currently I have a 2.2k resistor as base resistor, but that shouldn't be an issue right? Anyway ESP can output 10mA as max current from GPIO I think

Comment: Why do you need another led ? There is already one (or 2) on the ESP-01. Be careful because you connect an output (GPIO0) to a "potential" 5V. ESP-01 would not like it.

Comment: I will try without the LED or swap the 5V on the LED with 3.3V source

Comment: Yes. Swap +5V for the Led with 3.3V. Safer.

Comment: I don't know how you use this ESP-01. But I would not use Tx and Rx because there are needed for "programming" the device. I use this module for years with Domoticz with open source firmware (ESPeasy) and one can drive led onboard with internet call.

Comment: I used also this kind of board https://andrologiciels.wordpress.com/materiels-android/esp8266/esp01/relais-esp/esp-01s-relay-module/ Sorry, it is in french. or this https://www.letscontrolit.com/wiki/index.php?title=ESPEasy

Comment: @Antonio51 if we disable RX / TX then can't we use them as any other GPIOs? That's what I read - https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29938/how-to-i-make-the-tx-and-rx-pins-on-an-esp-8266-01-into-gpio-pins

Comment: Yes. You can. No worries. I use them as "RS232 spy" when connected to a PC.

Comment: @Amorphous, LED will drop the voltage when driven. driven only, Vak_ON@current. With some scenario 5V comes through to the 3.3V pin, while vcc wasn't established, then the pin gets latched. At the time 3.3V comes in, latched pins fuse. It may or may not happen, depends on many other factors, but foreseeable scenario it is. When something happens, you have to check more than less.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is there anything wrong with my schematic?*

If you are using a switch similar to this one: -

[image]

<sub>Image from [here](https://docs.rs-online.com/5010/0900766b80dbe05c.pdf) courtesy of RS components.</sub>

Then, the switching contacts are between pins 2 and 4 (or 1 and 3). Your schematic shows this: -

[image]

So, it looks possible that you may not have wired up the switch correctly. You can confirm this by linking the data sheet. In other words, between pins 1 and 2 is a dead short.

Of course, if you put a feeble switch like this directly across a 100 nF capacitor, when the switch closes, you get an almighty current surge into the switch that may weld the contacts closed. This type of switch has the following current rating: -

[image]

50 mA is just not going to cut-the-mustard when shorting out a charged capacitor if this switch is similar to the one used. Data sheet link required.

Comment: Infact I did screw up exactly like this earlier but then corrected it in my current prototype PCB. Can confirm that switch is wired correctly

Comment: I can't confirm that because I only have your schematic and no link to the device. However, I have pointed out another deficiency in your design; you may need a 100 ohm (or thereabouts) resistor in series with your switch to prevent it becoming damaged when you short out the capacitor (C7).

Comment: Thanks a ton. I will add a current limiting resistor in series with the switch..never thought of it..much appreciated

PS : Sorry I meant I can confirm that the switch is wired correctly (in the previous comment)

Comment: @Amorphous no problems and good luck (but you still didn't link the switch used because I like to nail these things down instead of leaving a slightly open-ended answer!)

Comment: Its a chinese switch, I will try & dig out the datasheet